# How to monkey patch Commontator::Comment (or any rails engine)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monkeypatching

I just recently learned the term monkey patching, so I'm not sure if I have it right.

I am using the Commontator gem to provide commenting functionality on my Blog (Monologue::Post models) and my other models. I ran into an issue where I was trying to get the parent object from my comment (ie, what was commented on). It looks like I would have to do three joins. Rather than call that in my controller, I thought I could extend the gem's model to have a function `comment_parent` that would return the parent model.

I have this:

```
# config/initializers/comment_model_extenders.rb
module Commontator
  class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    def comment_parent
      # do some magic
      "return parent here"
    end
  end
end
```

I must be doing it wrong, because I am getting this error:

```
irb(main):010:0> c=Commontator::Comment
=> Commontator::Comment(id: integer, creator_type: string, creator_id: integer, editor_type: string, editor_id: integer, thread_id: integer, body: text, deleted_at: datetime, cached_votes_up: integer, cached_votes_down:
integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
irb(main):011:0> c.comment_parent
NoMethodError: undefined method `comment_parent' for #<Class:0xab743d0>
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):11
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

**EDIT:**

Based off of Fredrick's comments, I changed my code to be

```
...
def self.comment_parent
...
```

but the output is as follows:

```
irb(main):022:0*  c=Commontator::Comment
=> Commontator::Comment(id: integer, creator_type: string, creator_id: integer, editor_type: string, editor_id: integer, thread_id: integer, body: text, deleted_at: datetime, cached_votes_up: integer, cached_votes_down:
integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
irb(main):023:0> c.comment_parent
=> "return parent here"
irb(main):024:0> test = c.find(1)
  Commontator::Comment Load (35.7ms)  SELECT  "commontator_comments".* FROM "commontator_comments"  WHERE "commontator_comments"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Commontator::Comment id: 1, creator_type: "User", creator_id: 2, editor_type: nil, editor_id: nil, thread_id: 2, body: "Love this parser.", deleted_at: nil, cached_votes_up: 0, cached_votes_down: 0, created_at: "201
5-02-12 22:04:48", updated_at: "2015-02-12 22:04:48">
irb(main):025:0> test.comment_parent
NoMethodError: undefined method `comment_parent' for #<Commontator::Comment:0xad08a10>
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activemodel-4.1.8/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:213:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):25
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You've added an instance method but you're trying to call it as a class method

Comment: Should I call it as a instance method or try to instantiate it as a class method (what did I do wrong)?

Comment: It depends - do you want an instance method or a class method

Comment: Reading this: http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/ makes me think that since I'm going to use it on every instance of the class... class method?

Comment: It's the other way around :) Think of the class as 'All comments' — 'all comments' does not have a parent, one specific comment does. So it has to be an instance method, and you need to call it on a comment instance.

Comment: I am debating deleting this post... but my code was correct for what I wanted. I just needed to call it on a single instance of the class not on the class itself.

Comment: I just took a brief look at Commontator, and I think you can already achieve what you want: from inside a comment, the parent object is referred to as  `creator`. See [here](https://github.com/lml/commontator/blob/master/lib/commontator/acts_as_commontator.rb): calling `acts_as_commontator` adds a `has_many :comments, as: :creator` to your model. No need for monkey patches :)

Comment: Creator_id seems to correspond to my user, not to the model it was posted on... I would somehow need to join the thread_id in comments, the commontable_type and commontable_id in threads, and the actual model that corresponds with that together.

Comment: Just posted my solution... I don't know if there is an easier way with joins (still can't get those down).

Comment: @Jeff you're right - sorry, I assumed that 'acts_as_commontator' was included on the parent, when it's included on the commentator (user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looking at the library](https://github.com/lml/commontator/blob/master/lib/commontator/acts_as_commontable.rb), your parent object `has_one :thread, :as => :commontable`, while the [thread](https://github.com/lml/commontator/blob/master/app/models/commontator/thread.rb) `has_many :comments`.

So, inside a `Comment`, `thread.commontable` should get you the other way around back up to your original parent.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, here is my solution:

In general, I wanted it to be called as an instance method, so my original code was correct. I was just calling it wrong. To call an instance method, do one of these:

```
Model.new.custom_method
```

or

```
my_model = Model.new #or .find(n)
my_model.custom_method
```

For my specific case, I found this solution:

```
module Commontator
  class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    def comment_parent
      # do some magic
      thread = Commontator::Thread.find(self.thread_id)
      parent_class = thread.commontable_type.camelize.constantize

      parent_class.find(thread.commontable_id)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Second try: it seems that you should be able to simply call `thread` in a comment to get the thread, and use `.commontable` from there to get to the parent object. So: `thread.commontable` should work inside a comment.

Comment: That is the real answer... my way is dumb... write an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Happy to hear it works! I hope that also solves [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509167/extending-rails-engine-model-removes-associations) in the process.